# Coherence over one sheaf but not another

Tags: algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathscr{R}$ and $\mathscr{T}$ be two sheaves of rings over a topological space $X$. If we take $\mathscr{S}$ to be a sheaf of abelian groups over $X$, we say that $\mathscr{S}$ is a coherent sheaf of $\mathscr{R}$-modules, or $\mathscr{T}$-modules, if for all $w \in X$, and integer $m \geq 0$, we have the existence of an open neighbourhood $U$ such that over $U$, $\mathscr{R}$ (resp. $\mathscr{T})$, admits a chain of syzygies of length $m$.

Can someone provide an elementary example of a sheaf $\mathscr{S}$ that is coherent with respect to one sheaf of rings $\mathscr{R}$ but not coherent with respect to $\mathscr{T}$?

Please note that I am aware of the way many algebraic geometers define a coherent sheaf. That is, in Hartshorne, we have the following definition: Let $(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$ be a scheme. A sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules $\mathscr{F}$ is quasi-coherent if $X$ can be covered by open affine subsets $U_i = \text{Spec} A_i$, such that for each $i$ there is an $A_i$-module $M_i$ with $\mathscr{F} \vert_{U_i} \cong \widetilde{M}_i$. We say that $\mathscr{F}$ is coherent if furthermore each $M_i$ can be taken to be a finitely generated $A_i$-module.

I would rather however stick to the chain of syzygies definition.

References for what I am reading are: Gunning and Rossi's *Analytic Functions of Several Complex Variables* and Kaup and Kaup's *Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables*.

Comment: Perhaps the last calligraphic $S$ is supposed to be a $T$?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, thank you. I have made the appropriate edit.

Comment: What if $X$ is a one-point space?

Comment: I am unsure about your hypotheses and your definition. I assume that you mean that $\mathcal{S}$ is already a sheaf of $\mathcal{R}$ and of $\mathcal{T}$ modules. Otherwise the question is trivial (see Phil. Z's comment). But I am also not sure about your definition of coherent. Surely it can't be for all $m$ (what if $m=1$ ?), and it also seems to imply that any sheaf of rings is coherent over itself.

Comment: Anyway if $\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent, a good example of non coherent sheaf is $\mathcal{O}_X^{(\mathbb{N})}$. Surely you can cook up an easy example with this. If you meant quasi-coherent instead, you can look at $\mathcal{R}=j_!\mathcal{O}_U$, $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{R}$ (here $j_!$ is the functor extension by zero outside the open set $U$).

Comment: @Roland According to Gunning and Rossi, it is for all $m$, but we do permit the open neighbourhood to change according to $m$. That is, we let shrink or enlarge depending on the $m$.